# Weighted joint probability incorporating zeroes

Tags: probability, statistics

I have multiple observations $X = \{x_i\}$ and several possible outcomes $R = \{r_j\}$. From previous data I can estimate the conditional probabilities $p(x_i | r_j)$. I want to weigh recent observations higher, so I use

$p(X | r_j) = \prod_i p(x_{i,\tau}|r_j)^{w_i(\tau)}$

As my training data is incomplete probabilities for individual items may be 0, so I ignore these values to guarantee $p(X | r_j) > 0$.

My problem is that this gives me spurious results for certain inputs. For example, an event chain $p(X|r_j) = [0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0]$ would give me a high rating for $r_j$ although the last observations no longer support this claim. To spell this out the formula says *"the part I know fits well"*, but I want it to say *"this part fit well, but it's pretty old, so..."*.

For this reason I would like to use a weighted average instead, but I lack the theoretical basis to justify this (i.e. I'm not aware of a meaning of averaged probabilities).

To rephrase as a question: suspecting that there is no sound way to incorporate zeroes into a weighted joint probability, what am I actually calculating when I calculate $\frac{1}{\sum_i w_i(t)} \sum_i p(x_{i,t}|r_j) * w_i(t)$ and what alternatives do I have to take zeroes into account?

Comment: You seem to be using *inputs*, *observations* and *outcomes* rather freely.  You might do better with something like a Bayesian approach using priors (to deal with limited training data) and using likelihoods (so proportionality)

Comment: @Henry can you elaborate a bit? This is within a bayesian context, but I'm not very firm in the matter.